# удаление элемента из вектора со своей структурой

Tags: c++

Как удалить элемент из вектора в котором находится своя структура? Например:

```
std::vector<pica*> Picas;
```

Добавлять понятно через `push_back`. Далее я циклом for пробегаю по всем элементам в векторе `for(auto pica1 : Picas)`. И как мне потом этот элемент удалить `pica1` в векторе? Через `erase`? Но я не знаю итератор этого элемента.

Пытаюсь через `find` найти итератор: `auto find_it = std::find(Picas.begin(), Picas.end(), pica1);` При удалении элемента через erase: `Picas.erase(Picas.begin()+find_it);` Выдает ошибку:

> бинарный "+": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа
>   "std::_Vector_iterator>>"
>   (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Comment: Можно чуточку больше кода?

Comment: вы хотите удалить указатель на конкретный обьект  pica1 ? В вашем вопросе не понятно что за элемент, про который вы ведете речь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробегайте не по значениям, а по итераторам

```
for(auto pica1 = Picas.begin(); pica1 != Picas.end(); ++pica1)...
```

Но если вы хотите удалять все элементы - то просто

```
Picas.clear()
```

И еще 2 замечания. Если вы что-то удаляете через `erase()` - то итератор элемента и все после него инвалидируются, так что цикл после этого просто так продолжаться не может. И, на всякий случай - при удалении указателя (у вас же в векторе указатели) для него не вызывается `delete`, вы же в курсе?

Comment: Еще есть такой вопрос. Пытаюсь через `find` найти индекс элемента: `auto find_it = std::find(Picas.begin(), Picas.end(), pica1);`И когда в `erase` пытаюсь удалить элемент по данному итератору:`Picas.erase(Picas.begin()+find_it);`, то он ругается на сумму: отсутствует оператор "+", соответствующий этим операндам

Comment: `find` возвращает итератор, так что после проверки `find_it != Picas.end()` просто вызываете `Picas.erase(find_it)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
pica pica1;
auto It = Picas.begin();
while (*It != &pica1 && It != Picas.end()) ++It;
if(It != Picas.end()) //если найден
    Picas.erase(It);
```

Вы пытались найти через std::find. Это тоже является одним из многих вариантов, и вы уже будете иметь итератор на этот элемент, и вам не нужен `Picas.begin()`, тем более что к итератору произвольного доступа  можете добавлять целочисленное значение, но никак другой итератор... Вот как:

```
auto find_it = std::find(Picas.begin(), Picas.end(), &pica1);
if(find_it != Picas.end()) //если найден    
    Picas.erase(find_it);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+i);
```

, где i - это индекс элемента

Comment: Это я понимаю, но я не знаю индекс элемента. Пытался найти его так:  `std::find(Picas.begin(), Picas.end(), pica1)`, но выдает ошибку

Comment: Попробуйте искать счётчиком for (int i = 0; i < Picas.length; i++) или что-то в этом роде. Насколько я помню, векторы - это более гибкая замена массивам и их можно итерировать обычным счётчиком по индексу

Comment: А ещё можно использовать итератор как-то так: for(i = Picas.begin(); i < Picas.end(); i++) { /*проверяешь тот ли это обьект и удаляешь его, если тот*/ }

Comment: Вообще ты пробовал гуглить векторы на C++? Материала же навалом!